# validate css3: Parse Error *zoom (or *marging, *width and etc.)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

what effect has * in the bootstrap.css? I am trying to validate my website's css and it shows me this:

"Sorry! We found the following errors (676)"  and

Parse Error *zoom: 1;

Parse Error *width:

and etc.

I want to know what will happen, if i remove those lines, where *(css-attribute) exists

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [CSS Star Hack](http://www.phpied.com/the-star-hack-in-ie8-and-dynamic-stylesheets/). It allows you to target specific browsers through some CSS hacks that only several browsers can read due to their parsing engine.

Here's an example:

```
.box {
    background: red; /* normal browsers */
    *background: blue;  /* IE 6 and 7 */
    _background: green; /* IE6 */
}
```

You're getting those error messages since the validator doesn't allow/recognize these hacks.

Comment: The reason the validator doesn't recognise the hacks is because they work by being invalid. The CSS spec requires that browsers ignore the invalid rule. Bugs in the browsers mean they are not ignored.